# wxPython: onPaint event not called on panel update

Tags: windows, wxpython

The following code is supposed to create a window consisting of a "calibrate" button and a canvas. When the "calibrate" button is clicked, the red dot is supposed to be re-drawn on a random location on the canvas.

Instead, I see the OnPaint event is called once, in the beginning, and not afterwards. Any idea what's going on?

```
import wx 
import datetime
import threading
import random 

class frmMain ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 839,553 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.pos = (300,100)
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        topSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        buttonsSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.btnCalibrate = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Calibrate", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        buttonsSizer.Add( self.btnCalibrate, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        topSizer.Add( buttonsSizer, 0, wx.LEFT, 5 )

        sizeCanvas = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        sizeCanvas.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 600,600 ) ) 

        self.panel=wx.Panel(self, size=(600,600))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.firstpoint=wx.Point(300,300)
        self.secondpoint=wx.Point(400,400)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint)

        sizeCanvas.Add(self.panel, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)

        topSizer.Add( sizeCanvas, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( topSizer )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.btnCalibrate.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.StartCalibrate )
        self.Show(True)

    def onPaint(self,event):
        print "lalal"
        dc = wx.WindowDC(self.panel) 
        color = wx.Colour(255,0,0)
        b = wx.Brush(color) 

        dc.SetBrush(b)
        dc.DrawCircle(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], 10)

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    def StartCalibrate( self, event ):
        size = self.GetSize()
        self.pos = (random.randrange(0, size[0] - 1, 1), random.randrange(0, size[1] - 1, 1))
        print "fixation at %d, %d" % (self.pos[0], self.pos[1])
        self.panel.Update()
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frmMain(None) 
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Refresh` instead of `Update`.  `Update` causes any pending paint events to be processed immediately, but if there are no pending paint events then nothing will be done.  On the other hand, `Refresh` causes a paint event to be sent to the widget.